# Checkstyle config used by Maven and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, checkstyle

I am try to use the same Checkstyle configuration file with both Maven and Eclipse. The module SuppressionCommentFilter works as expected in Eclipse, but Maven reports 
 TreeWalker is not allowed as a parent of SuppressionCommentFilter
If I move it from TreeWalker to Checker the error goes away, but Checkstyle does not process the ignore comments. I am using Checkstyle 8.12 with Eclipse, but have not found a way to use other than 6.18 with Maven. Since this module had been part of Checkstyle since 3.5 I don't see how that could be the problem. Any suggestions what is wrong?

```
<module name="Checker">
<property name="severity" value="warning" />
<module name="TreeWalker">
    <property name="tabWidth" value="4" />
    <module name="SuppressionCommentFilter" />
```

---

Mark asked what the  looks like, so here is that piece of code.

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>verify-style</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The pom and Checkstyle config file are all working correctly other than the
    
If it is a child of Treewalker I get the error from the Maven plugin, but not from the Eclipse plugin, however I can only get it to work with the Eclipse plugin.

Comment: What checkstyle version do you have in your `pom.xml`?

Comment: For the answer to this question please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52957725/checkstyle-suppressioncommentfilter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using Checkstyle 8.12 with Eclipse, but have not found a way to use other than 6.18 with Maven

You must override the dependency in maven to bring in newer versions of Checkstyle. By default, the maven plugin will only use 6.18 but it can be overridden for newer versions.

See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/upgrading-checkstyle.html

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have defined checkstyle as dependency and not as plugin.

Using the guide at [Apache Maven Checkstyle](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/usage.html) I was able to use checkstyle for my personal projects. This is a snippet from the `plugins` section of my `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>verify-style</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>

    <configuration>
        <logViolationsToConsole>true</logViolationsToConsole>
        <configLocation>yourcheckstylexmlhere.xml</configLocation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

[Maskime](https://github.com/jshiell/checkstyle-idea/issues/341#issuecomment-323022474) on GitHub says:

> Dear reader if you googled your way here, like I did, the solution is
>   to move the `<module name="SuppressionCommentFilter"/>` under the
>   `TreeWalker` module.

I have tried this fix with the version you're using aswell and it does not give the error anymore.

Comment: Everything with the pom and config file is working just fine. The only problem is with the SuppressionCommentFilter module.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but your answer did not address the problem of how to get the SuppressionCommentFilter module to work with Maven when it works just fine with Eclipse.