# Checkstyle SuppressionCommentFilter

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, checkstyle

I am sharing my Checkstyle configuration between Eclipse and Maven and that is working fine. The issue I need help with is the SuppressionCommentFilter module.  The following is a snippet of the configuration file.

```
<module name="Checker">
<property name="severity" value="warning" />
<module name="TreeWalker">
    <property name="tabWidth" value="4" />
    <module name="SuppressionCommentFilter" />
```

This works as expected in Eclipse (Checkstyle version 8.12) but Maven (plugin 3.0.0, Checkstyle 6.18) gives the error

```
TreeWalker is not allowed as a parent of SuppressionCommentFilter
```

Yes, I know if I do the follow the error goes away, but then it does not process the suppression lines in the Java files.

```
<module name="Checker">
<property name="severity" value="warning" />
<module name="SuppressionCommentFilter" />
<module name="TreeWalker">
    <property name="tabWidth" value="4" />
```

Any suggestion how to resolve this problem so both Eclipse and Maven can use this configuration file?

Comment: It asks the same question but the answers were not useful and should be ignored.. The following answer is exactly is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: The same answer was posted there before this one.